# Can't get file upload using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

Multer should put the file data in req.file, but req.file is undefined.

#### Here is the request I'm making with the file:

[image]

#### Here is my nodejs code:

```
//routes.js
import candidatesRouter from './candidates';
export default function routes(app) {
  app.use('/v1/candidates', candidatesRouter);
}
```

```
//candidates.js
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
export default express
  .Router()
  .post('/:userId/documents/:objectKey', upload.any(), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body); // undefined
    console.log(req.file); // undefined
    console.log(req.files); // []
  });
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());
```

then check req.files again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is because I was using Swagger Middleware. https://apidevtools.org/swagger-express-middleware/docs/middleware/parseRequest.html Swagger Middleware already handles parsing the form data, and stores it in req.files by default.